# Akka actor lookup or dependency injection

Tags: akka, actor

I'm just starting to work with Akka and I can't decide if I should use dependency injection (like cake pattern) or actor lookup in order to decouple the actors from each others. What is the preferred method?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should prefer to introduce actors to each other, which means to send an ActorRef in or with a message or to pass it into a constructor. The latter may involve the cake pattern of you so choose, but lookup is much more expensive and therefore you should use real ActorRef whenever possible.

Comment: I imagined so, but I was planning to use the lookup in the initialisation phase, not each time they were needed. That being said I still tend to agree with you and use the more classical type of dependency injection though I don't have a proper reason in mind.

Comment: The comment about lookups being more expensive was not only meant with regards to runtime cost, the implementation cost is also considerably higher as you intuitively figured out.

Comment: WIsh there were more opinions and explanations.

Comment: But ActorRef changes if the actor is restarted right? So the passed ActorRef would not work anymore. If ever that actor restarted.

Comment: No, ActorRef stays valid across a restart—this is the difference between Akka and Erlang. Only when the actor terminates does the ActorRef become invalid.

Comment: Is this also valid for a clustered Akka setup?